# Do I obtain Azure Consumed Revenue (ACR) from all resources of all Azure Active Directory tenants?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If I am a partner and I want to link my Partner Admin Link I go to the portal of my customer and I enter the Microsoft Partner ID, but my question is the follow:
If I link the partner ID in Azure portal, Do I obtain Azure Consumed Revenue (ACR) from all resources of all Azure Active Directory tenants?

I'll be waiting for your answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All resources within the linked tenant so you would need to link your partner ID for each customer tenant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/615295/do-i-obtain-azure-consumed-revenue-acr-from-all-re.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For the linked tenant you will get for other client tenants you need to add your partnerID.